# Why is my nsurl request not showing up in console?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get the redirected url to show up in console. I may be missing a minor detail somewhere in my code.Any help will be appreicated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 119,     self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 165)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
webView.opaque = NO;
[webView loadHTMLString:self.item.description baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.item.link]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
webView.delegate = self;
}


 - (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
         willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
//Make sure tinyurl is doing the redirection
if([[[redirectResponse URL] host] compare:@"bitly.com"
                                  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    NSLog(@"Redirect Location: %@", [request URL]);
}

//call [connection cancel]; to cancel the redirect and stop receiving data
//return nil; to cancel redirect but continue receiving data
//return request; will continue the redirection as normal
    return request;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using delegate method of [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection%3awillSendRequest%3aredirectResponse%3a) it is not right method for `UIWebView`

You are not loading any request in the `UIWebView` either how do you expect `NSLog` to print out the request?
If you are using [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), then the right method to check in your case should be:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  {

  NSLog(@"Redirect Location: %@",[request.URL absoluteString]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
         willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

That isn't a UIWebView Delegate Method. So unless you're not showing all your code its never getting called.

You need to create an NSURLConnection to take advantage of that call like so.

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```